How can I insert the content of multiple files to a single file using blockinfile or any other approach?
I have 10 files and I want those content to be copied to a single file.
The content of 10 files should be separated by their filenames respectively (similar to header as in blockinfile).
Example
$ cat /tmp/file1.txt # -> This is first file
$ cat /tmp/file2.txt # -> This is second file

Expected Result from cat /tmp/merged_file
ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK file1.txt
This is first file
ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK file1.txt
ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK file2.txt
This is second file
ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK file2.txt

If its only 1 file, it can be achieved with blockinfile. I would like to know if above can be achieved through blockinfile or any other feasible approach.

Can you provide more context and describe your Use Case in more detail? What kind of files are these? For which software, service or what kind of config files? Are the files on Remote Managed Nodes? Or are they on the Control Node only?

You can achieve it by using the following syntax

name: block in file with items
blockinfile:
dest: /tmp/file.txt
insertafter: BOF
state: present
block: |
{{item}}
marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{item}}"
with_items:
- /tmp/file1.txt
- /tmp/file2.txt
- /tmp/file3.txt


Here is the file structure for this example:
.
├── files
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   └── file3.txt
├── playbook.yml
└── resultdir

resultdir is empty
The content files are as follows:
$ for f in files/*; do echo -en "---\n$f\n---\n"; cat $f; echo; done
---
files/file1.txt
---
file1 content

---
files/file2.txt
---
file2 content

---
files/file3.txt
---
yet an other file content

The following playbook.yml:
- name: Concat files to single with blockinfile
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Add each file in `files` subfolder to a block in result
      ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
        marker: '{mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ item | ansible.builtin.basename }}'
        block: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', item) }}"
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/resultdir/merged.txt"
        create: true
      loop: "{{ q('ansible.builtin.fileglob', playbook_dir ~ '/files/*.txt') }}"

Gives:
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [Concat files to single with blockinfile] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Add each file in `files` subfolder to a block in result] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=/home/user/tmp/filesinblocks/files/file1.txt)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/home/user/tmp/filesinblocks/files/file3.txt)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/home/user/tmp/filesinblocks/files/file2.txt)

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

And the result in merged.txt is:
$ cat resultdir/merged.txt 
BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK file1.txt
file1 content
END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK file1.txt
BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK file3.txt
yet an other file content
END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK file3.txt
BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK file2.txt
file2 content
END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK file2.txt

Notes:

In case you wonder, q in the above playbook is a shortcut to query
If you change the content of an existing file, it will be updated accordingly.
If you add a file it will be added at the end of the merged file
This playbook does not take deletion in charge (i.e. remove a block if you delete or rename a file). Meanwhile you can easily delete the result file before running the playbook again to start from scratch (but you will loose idempotency in that case).
The fileglob lookup does not follow lexicographic order of file names. If this is a problem, you can sort the result (i.e. loop: "{{ q('ansible.builtin.fileglob', playbook_dir ~ '/files/*.txt') | sort }}". Meanwhile, be aware that new files added to the dir will still be added to the end of the merged file unless you recreate it from scratch.


Using GNU awk for BEGINFILE, ENDFILE, and gensub() and a shell such as bash that supports {1..10} brace expansion notation:
awk '
    BEGINFILE { str = "ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK " gensub(".*/","",1,FILENAME); print str }
    { print }
    ENDFILE { print str }
' /tmp/file{1..10}.txt

